# Selected Image downloading using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I have an application which creates custom images in the backend. Stores the link in a db table and then they are showed on a UI with checkboes attached to each of them.Now i want the user to be able to click on a download button and then all the images whose checkboxes are selected should get download (and not rendered) in one of the two ways possible
1.) create a zip file of selected and then download(future scope)
2.) download all images individually one by one.

below is my html code

```
<div class="span5" data-type="collage-image-structure">
<input type="checkbox" class="images_checkbox" data-url="some_url_of_image.png" checked="checked or unchecked">
<img src="some_url_of_image.png"> 
</div>
```

Now on click of a button I want download images that are checked. I have tried the iframe solution provided that i read somewhere on stackoverflow(sorry i cant find the link right now). The solution downloads the image in an empty iframe but does not show the download popup as traditional browsers. Also providing a link in the  tag and using the download attribute solves things but i dont want to attach an  tag to every image. All i want is to write a javascript function that will pass image_urls one by one and download them.Also i do not want to use any readymade plugins available to avoid the overhead of loading the jS file everytime with page load.Please help I need a solution quickly.

Comment: That's done on the backend...what are you using for your backend?  Here's a good example in PHP: http://snipplr.com/view/22546/

Comment: I am not using php. my backend is in ruby on rails and mysql for the database

Comment: I don't know ruby, but it's still the same principle...you have to declare the headers of the file on the backend.